# Copying and renaming of .xlsm files using batch

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, batch, batch-file

Its glad to be here and i am really excited n new to batch scripting. I have been using a batch containing below for copying an excel from one folder to another

```
{
@echo off

cp -r \\Folder1\DELMIAIndustrialEngineering_2016_TaskDashboard.xlsm C:\Users\nv2\Folder2
}
```

All i wanted is to rename this .xlsm file while copying it in folder2 so that i have all the copies stored with `.xlsm1, .xlsm2, .xlxm3` and so on batch is executed. would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: To confirm, you want the file to increment in number if it already exists when copied?

Comment: exactly, you got my requirement. Could you provide the script for the same

Comment: You do realise that if you rename to `.xlsm1` excel won't open the file with a double click?

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it by Date? Use this If you dont want to do it that way i will delete this post I just think its helpful by date.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" rem & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

echo copying file
copy "C:\Users\MBurris\Documents\Updated Software\Testing\Test_DTC.txt" "C:\Users\MBurris\Documents\Testing Folder\Test_DTC %DD%%MM%%YYYY%.txt"  >nul
echo done
pause
```

Test it out by Entering your information.

Comment: Worth noting if doing it by date to do it in ISO 8601 format of YYYY-MM-DD, this way it'll sort in ascending or descending order when sorted by filename as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET SOURCE_FOLDER=C:\Source Folder
SET TARGET_FOLDER=D:\Target Folder
SET /A COUNT=1
CD %SOURCE_FOLDER%

for %%F in (*.xlsm) do (
Copy "%%~nxF" "%TARGET_FOLDER%\%%~nxF!COUNT!"
SET /A COUNT+=1
)
```

Replace

```
C:\Source Folder
D:\Target Folder
1
```

to set your own folder and counting number start. this batch will start at 1.

---

if *C:\Source Folder* have the Following files: **File1.xlsm, File2.xlsm & File3.xlsm**

after running the batch, *D:\Target Folder* will have copies of the three files, named: **File1.xlsm1, File2.xlsm2 & File3.xlsm3**